# timestamp formatting in scala

Tags: java, scala

IP:

```
test: String = 2018-10-12 07
```

Expected OP:

```
test_timestamp: Timestamp = 2018-10-12 07
```

Code:

```
val format1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH")
var d = format1.parse(test)
var date =    new Date(d.getTime())
var timestamp = new Timestamp(d.getTime())
```

My OP:

```
timestamp: java.sql.Timestamp = 2018-10-12 07:00:00.0
```

I am trying to convert to the same datehour format.

Code:

```
var dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH");
timestamp = dateFormat.format(timestamp);
```

Error:

```
found   : String
required: java.sql.Timestamp
timestamp = dateFormat.format(timestamp);
                                ^
```

the variable "timestamp" is clearly of type java.sql.Timestamp, so I am not able to understand the issue. Any suggestions.

Comment: If you know that `timestamp` *"is clearly of type java.sql.Timestamp"*, then why are you trying to assign a `String` to a variable of type java.sql.Timestamp?

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I am trying only to convert the format of the timestamp to the datehour. Not sure how this is assigning a string. Could you please explain.

Comment: The variable `timestamp` is of type `java.sql.Timestamp`. The output of `dateFormat.format(...)` is of type `String`. You cannot assign a `String` to a variable of type `java.sql.Timestamp`, because `String` is not a subtype of `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Got it. Any suggestions on how to format the timestamp without converting it back to String.

Comment: *"format"* and *"without converting [...] to String"* is self-contradictory. Just pick *any other variable name* that is not "timestamp" to hold the `String` result.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Got it.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin what I meant was how to change the representation of the timestamp to 'yyyy-MM-dd HH' without converting its type to string

Comment: In this case I don't understand what you mean by "representation". What other non-`String` representation do you want? As byte array? As barcode? Could you please clarify the question, I'm not sure what exactly is being asked. The error message in the current  version of the question stems from the attempt to reassign a `String` to a variable of type `java.sql.Timestamp`, this doesn't seem to be what you are asking in your last comment.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin. i have given that in the expected OP. When I am trying to convert a String to Timestamp, the format I need is "yyyy-MM-dd HH", but the op after converting to timestamp is "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:SS". Any suggestions on how I can remove the minutes and seconds from the timestamp

Comment: `2018-10-12 07:00:00.0` is not a properly formatted `String`, it's just the output of `Timestamp`s `toString` method that should be used for debugging purposes only, and shouldn't be taken too seriously. You should not care how `Timestamp`s are displayed in the REPL, and you should not rely on any particular format used by `toString`. Since you already seem to know how to obtain a String in the format that you actually *do* want, I'm not sure what there's left to answer.

Comment: By the way: [here is the code that generates the "2018-10-12 07:00:00.0"-output](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-dev-jdk/blob/master/src/share/classes/java/sql/Timestamp.java#L350). There is no way to configure it. The only way to change it in the REPL would be to recompile the Java standard library, or tweak some inner details of the REPL itself. But, again, this is just the `toString` output that shouldn't be used for anything but debugging.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin Thanks. Got it.

Comment: @OleV.V. Good duplicate candidate, unfortunately I can't dupe-hammer it, because I've already voted to close as "trivial typo".

Comment: There are many similar questions asking for a `java.util.Date`, a `Calendar`, a `LocalDate`, a `java.sql.Date` with a particular format. I don’t know if there’s already one asking for a `Timestamp` with a particular format, probably somewhere. In any case, the issue is the same as in this question, and the answer is the same too. Thanks, @AndreyTyukin, for supporting that this is a duplicate.

Comment: @OleV.V. Yes there maybe someone asking for a particular format, that could be because the headings of the question would have been something different and it wouldn't have shown up in the search. In any case, you can probably try changing the headings for all the questions in this category so that next time we wont ask for a particular format:)