# converting String to Timestamp gives extra '0'

Tags: java, timestamp

I am converting **String** to **Timestamp** but output format has extra '0'.

Below is the code.

**Code:**

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;

public class StringToTimeStamp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String date = "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00";


        SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");


        try {
            java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
            System.out.println(parsedDate);
            Timestamp time = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
            System.out.println(time);

        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

**Output**

```
Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2017
2017-01-01 00:00:00.0
```

**Expected output**

```
Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2017
2017-01-01 00:00:00
```

I am not able to understand why extra '0' is there in output?

**JDK version : 1.8.0_191**

**EDIT**

I tried formatting my timestamp instance like this :

```
System.out.println(dateFormat.format(time));
```

It gave below output :

```
Sun Jan 01 00:00:00 IST 2017
2017-01-01T00:00:00
```

It removed '0' but added 'T'.

Comment: Can you kindly tell which Java version are you using?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42372261/unexplained-zero-added-when-going-from-java-util-date-to-java-sql-timestamp

Comment: At that point, you are not printing a formatted String, but the timestamp instance. The formatting doesn't apply to that

Comment: @darshgohel jdk1.8.0_191

Comment: @Stultuske but how to get the expected output?

Comment: @Stultuske okay so you mean I need to format it as well.

Comment: You can checkout the link provided by @AtulSharma

Comment: Use another formatter

Comment: @AtulSharma but then output is like : 2017-01-01T00:00:00 and not  2017-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: @ScaryWombat which one? I have updated my question again , can you please check.

Comment: Either use formatters or got for string manipulation choice is yours.

Comment: what part of `another` did you not understand in my above comment?

Comment: @AtulSharma That situation is different. They are getting 00:00:00.001 instead of 00:00:00.01, which is a different *value*. This question is about a different *format*.

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`, `Date` and `Timestamp`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated, the first in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `OffsetDateTime` and `Instant`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting timestamp in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692117/formatting-timestamp-in-java) and/or [timestamp formatting in scala [duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841451/timestamp-formatting-in-scala)

Comment: While not parsing the fractional seconds of your string gives an inaccuracy at worst, you are also ignoring the offset, -05:00, which introduces an error. If IST is India Standard Time (many other interpretations exist), then you string represents a point in time of Sun Jan 01 **10:30**:00 IST 2017. `System.out.println(time);` implicitly calls `time.toString`, and the `toString` method of the `Timestamp` class (that you should avoid using anyway) always prints at least one decimal on the seconds, there is no way to avoid that.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Smart objects, not dumb strings

Be sure you understand that a date-time object is *not* text, is not the same as a `String`.

A date-time object can generate a string containing text that represents the value. That string can be created following all kinds of different formats localized for all kinds of locales. And a date-time object can be instantiated by parsing an input string, after translating into a value for the object. But the string and the date-time object are separate and distinct.

Use date-time objects throughout your codebase whenever practical, rather than relying on mere strings.

## *java.time*

You are using terrible date-time classes that were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes. Never use `java.util.Date` nor `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Parse your input string as a `OffsetDateTime` object.

```
String input = "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00" ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input ) ;
```

If your goal is storing this value as a member variable in your class, make that member variable of type `OffsetDateTime` rather than `String`.

The `toString` method generates text in standard ISO 8601 format.

To generate text in other formats, use the `DateTimeFormatter` class. This class has been covered many times already, so search Stack Overflow to learn more.

Be wary of generating strings that represent a moment yet omit an indicator of the time zone or offset-from-UTC. That is like reporting an amount of money while neglecting to mention the currency.

```
DateTimeFormatter f =  DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" ) ;
String output = odt.format( f ) ;
```

Comment: it gives output as 2017-01-01T00:00-05:00, I need 2017-01-01 00:00:00

Comment: @ALearner  Are you trying to submit this to a database?

Comment: @ALearner What is a VO?

Comment: it is Java POJO

Comment: Best to change your value object POJO to contain an `Instant` (or other modern type) instead of a `Timestamp`. @ALearner

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following code. I have added a new formatter and converted the timestamp to the correct format you need.

I have added the following approach assuming that you need to format a date and print it and at the same time to format the timestamp and convert it too.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws ParseException {
    String date = "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000-05:00";
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss");
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat2 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {
        java.util.Date parsedDate = dateFormat.parse(date);
        System.out.println(parsedDate);
        Timestamp time = new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
        System.out.println(dateFormat2.format(time.getTime()));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Comment: but it gives output as String

Comment: I want output as Timestamp

Comment: If I use Timestamp.valueOf(finalString) it adds 0 to it again

Comment: So don't do that. what exactly do you think System.out.println does? it prints a String, whether you specifically code it to or not

Comment: If you want to return a timestamp object, you can send it to the calling levels and whenever you need to print it or convert it to a string you will need to format it as I have mentioned.

Comment: These terrible date-time classes were supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes as of the adoption of JSR 310.

Answer (score 1):

You are printing a timestramp. kindly change it to string like below

```
  String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd HH.mm.ss").format(time);
```

it will give you expected result

Answer (score 1):

The extra "0" is for milliseconds. And to omit that you can follow below link,

[Converting java date to Sql timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856931/converting-java-date-to-sql-timestamp)

and from there this solution,
https://stackoverflow.com/a/22857062/1529092

```
java.util.Date utilDate = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Timestamp sq = new java.sql.Timestamp(utilDate.getTime());
System.out.println(sa); //this will print the milliseconds as the toString() has been written in that format

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println(sdf.format(timestamp)); //this will print without ms
```

Or you can use below link to convert in different formats,
[How to remove milliseconds from Date Object format in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21448500/how-to-remove-milliseconds-from-date-object-format-in-java)