# Is there a simple way to change a timestamp value containing seconds and ms to a timestamp value having hours and minutes?

Tags: java, jdbc, timestamp

So I have an object ('Task') that has an attribute 'Start Date' which is basically a Timestamp object. So this date is in this format 'YYYY/MM/dd hh:mm:ss:ms'. But for a test case I am authoring, I need this date to be in this format 'YYYY/MM/dd hh:mm'. Also it needs to be a timestamp object as I have to set this value back to the 'Task' object.

I have tried several approaches including the snippet shown below:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("YYYY-MM-dd hh:mm");
if (task.getStartDate() != null) {
     String newDate = formatter.format(task.getStartDate());
     Date date = formatter.parse(newDate);
     task.setStartDate(new Timestamp(date.getTime()));
}
```

I expected the value of the timestamp to be in the format '2018-12-30 09:54' but it resulted in '2018-12-30 09:54:00.0'. So the questions that I have in mind is:

1. Is there a way to not consider the seconds and millis in the Timestamp object?
2. If no, then, is the snippet provided an efficient way to update the Timestamp object?

Comment: How do you come to the conclusion that the timestamp has a format of '2018-12-30 09:54:00.0'? Timestamps are a wrapper around a milliseconds value (truncated to seconds) + a sub-second nanoseconds fraction. It has no 'format' by itself. Likely you are looking at its default `toString()` rendering.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but I thought that after specifying  DateFormatter it would parse the dates as per the date pattern provided.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Formatting timestamp in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692117/formatting-timestamp-in-java)

Comment: The `Timestamp` class is poorly designed and long outdated, and was designed for exchanging timestamps with an SQL database, not for any other purposes. Is there any way you can modify your `Task` object to use an `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/), instead? It’ll serve you much better.

Comment: Regardless of the answer to my previous question I recommend you don’t use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. Those classes are poorly designed and long outdated too, the former in particular notoriously troublesome. Instead use `LocalDateTime` and `DateTimeFormatter`, both from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). Depending on your exact requirements you can convert either an `Instant` or a `LocalDateTime` to a `Timestamp` that you can feed to your `Task` if necessary.

Comment: I think your understanding is wrong. When you print a `Timestamp`thereby implicitly calling its `toString` method, you always get that format, with seconds and at least one decimal on the seconds (more decimals if they are non-zero). It has nothing to do with the format you used for parsing the `Date`. Also a `Date` hasn’t got a format either, and you only passed the millisecond value of the `Date` to your `Timestamp`, so how could a format have been conveyed?

Comment: A date formatter is simply about converting between string and a date. It doesn't have any lasting formatting on the date value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TL;DR

1. Avoid the `Timestamp` class if you can. It’s poorly designed and long outdated.
2. To answer your questions, no, a `Timestamp` hasn’t got, as in cannot have a format (the same holds true for its modern replacement, `Instant` (or `LocalDateTime`)).
3. Under all circumstances avoid `SimpleDateFormat` and `Date`. The former in particular is notoriously troublesome, and both are long outdated too.

### Don’t put a format into your model class

You should not want an `Instant` nor a `Timestamp` with a specific format. Good practice in all but the simplest throw-away programs is to keep your user interface apart from your model and your business logic. The value of the `Instant` object belongs in your model, so keep your `Instant` or `Timestamp` there and never let the user see it directly. I hope that it’s clear to you that `2018-12-30 09:54` and `2018-12-30 09:54:00.0` represent the same value, the same `Timestamp`. Just like 17, 0017 and 0x11 represent the same integer value. When you adhere to what I said, it will never matter which format the `Instant` has got.

Whenever the user should see the date and time, this happens in the UI, not in the model. Format it into a `String` and show the string to the user. Similarly if you need a specific format for persistence or exchange with another system, format the `Instant` into a string for that purpose.

### java.time and JDBC 4.2

Also for exchange with your database over JDBC, provided that you’ve got a JDBC 4.2 compliant driver, prefer to use a type from java.time over `Timestamp`. If the datatype on the database side is `timestamp with time zone`, very clearly recommended for a timestamp, pass an `OffsetDateTime` like

```
   OffsetDateTime dateTime = yourInstant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
   yourPreparedStatement.setObject(4, dateTime);
```

Use `setObject`, not `setTimestamp`. Some drivers accept the `Instant` directly, without conversion to `OffsetDateTime`. If on the database side you need a mere `timestamp` (without time zone), use `LocalDateTime` in Java instead and pass one to `setObject` in the same way as above.

### PS There are errors in your format pattern string

In a format pattern string, uppercase `YYYY` is for week based year and only useful with a week number. For year use either `uuuu` or lowercase `yyyy`. Similarly lowercase `hh` is for hour within AM or PM from 01 through 12 and only useful with an AM or PM marker. For hour of day from 00 through 23 you need uppercase `HH`. These errors will give you incorrect dates and times in most cases. Using the wrong case of format pattern letters is a very common mistake. `SimpleDateFormat` generally doesn’t mind, it just gives incorrect results. The modern `DateTimeFormatter` does a somewhat better job of notifying you of such errors.

### Links

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.

**Related questions**

- [Formatting timestamp in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23692117/formatting-timestamp-in-java) about getting rid of the `.0` decimal on the second of a `Timestamp`.
- [timestamp formatting in scala [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52841451/timestamp-formatting-in-scala) about getting a `Timestamp` with only date and hour (no minute, second or fraction of second).
- [java parsing string to date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14546742/java-parsing-string-to-date) about uppercase `Y` for year in a format pattern string.
- [Comparing two times in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20321711/comparing-two-times-in-android) about lowercase `h` for hour of day in a format pattern string.

Comment: Thanks Mark, Ole for detailed explanation. I have a better understanding on Timestamps now. Looks like I had incorrect expectations. I guessed what caused this confusion is while debugging, it showed the value of the timestamp in '2018-12-30 09:54' pattern.